# PHP PDO insert of directory path of images inside of an array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying put the directory path of the images that I've got inside of a MySQL DB using PHP-PDO, but I don't know how could I put an array of paths inside of the DB.

My Table SQL (tbl_images):
[image]

My PHP to multiple uploads of images:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    # INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    # PASTA
    $folder     = 'uploads';

    # REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    # MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
        3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
    );

    if($numFile <= 0)
        echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
    else{
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type   = $file['type'][$i];
            $size   = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
            else{

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)):
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";
                    $imgpath[] = $folder.'/'.$novoNome;
                    else:
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";
                endif;
            }

            foreach($msg as $pop)
                echo $pop.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in **$imgpath[]** are my directory path images, now I'm trying create a query to put this directory path in DB as array, How Can I Do that? (Sorry for my bad english).

Comment: easiest. put it as CSV (coma separated values). you can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: why you going for array ?. you are saving a single path only right.

Comment: bansi and Vigneswaran S: I tried to put the array only in a row of the table, it was my mistake, it's better put a FK in the table that reference each image to create a query specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can loop through your array and insert into db.

```
    $sql = "insert into tbl_images (img_name) values ";
    foreach ($imgpath as $path) {
        $sql .= " ('$path'),";
     } 
     $sql = substr ($sql,0,strlen ($sql)-1);
     $result = $db->exec($sql);
```